# How and why google cloud endpoints use sockets?

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, quota

I have a google cloud endpoints project uses sound cloud api(java-api-wrapper). according to socket resource quota report in appEngine/quoataDetails, project use intensively sockets but i dont use Java Socket Api and any Socket class etc. so how can it be possible? Is it related to http(s) calls?

Comment: Depends, what are you using as a library for your HTTP calls?

Comment: i just use this lib https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper

Comment: You probably want to take a look at that API to see if it uses sockets (hint: it uses HTTP).